# PHP echo/print on the base of null value Retrieved from Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, echo

This is one table (tbl_deep_breathing) from db, as shown below.

[image]

What I'm trying to is when I select from table where column is empty, it should echo **Empty**.
Below is my code:

```
$array=array("deep_breathing_Q2");
$query = $db_obj->selectSRow($array,"tbl_deep_breathing");
if(!empty($query))
echo "Data";
else
echo "Empty";
exit;
```

OR

```
$array=array("deep_breathing_Q2");
$query = $db_obj->selectSRow($array,"tbl_deep_breathing");
if(!is_null($query))
echo "Data";
else
echo "Empty";
exit;
```

OR

```
$array=array("deep_breathing_Q2");
$query = $db_obj->selectSRow($array,"tbl_deep_breathing");
if($query!="")
echo "Data";
else
echo "Empty";
exit;
```

All of above three codes are getting me **Data** in output, where it should print **Empty**.
Please suggest some solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Please add result of `var_dump($query)` in your question its giving the whole row from table and you have to check the specific column

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" ["deep_breathing_Q2"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: I'm just asking on the bases of query, if statement executes the output, as deep_breathing_Q2 is empty so it should echo Empty, but it echo's Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check if your element is `empty` not the `array` because your `$query` is not null but `$query['deep_breathing_Q2'])` is null , this should work :

```
if(!empty($query['deep_breathing_Q2']))
```

Answer (score 0):

OR Simply `if(is_null($query['deep_breathing_Q2']))` will work